# Return unique row identifier from an SQL query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I know this question may sound as a repetition. However, even though I found similar questions, I got nothing precise. I don't want to remove any duplicate values returned from my query. **What I want is to get a unique identifier for example a serial number for a result that is returned from an sp**. I tried using the Row_Number(). But, even that did not work since it should be partitioned based on a non repetitive column. My results need not have a non repetitive column. Rank and dense rank are also out the picture. So, what should I do to get a serial number type of column that uniquely identifies each rows. Also these rows should be int. Here is an example:

```
 empName empSalary
 Peter   10000
 Schott  20000
 Schott  10000
```

table should have one more column like this:

```
Slno  empName  empSalary
 1     Peter    10000
 2     Schott   20000
 3     Schott   10000
```

Comment: Add sample data and expected result

Comment: Also note `Partition By` is not mandatory in `ROW_NUMBER` you can generate unique number like this also `ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order by order_column)`

Comment: I have added a sample data for reference

Comment: On what order you want to generate `Slno`. Is it `Order by empName asc , empSalary desc`

Comment: The order does not matter. I am fine with anything.  My aim is to get a column that can be used to identify the rows independently even if there are repetitions and joins and large number of data returned.

Comment: row_number() will always return an increasing sequence 1,2,3,4,5 - so you can actually order over any single field  - where you give no tie breaker, that sequence doesn't have to be repeated for the same data though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't care about the ordering:

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (Select 1)) as SlNo ,*
from table
```

OR

Handle it in #temp table:

```
Select * into #TempTable from SourceTable
ALTER TABLE tempdb.dbo.#TempTable ADD SlNo INT IDENTITY(1,1) ;

Select * from #TempTable
```

Comment: Even though both the answers provided are correct, I feel this is the better one since it gave me more options. Did not think about the temp table.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks pretty straight forward.

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order by empName asc , empSalary desc) as Slno,
       empName,
       empSalary
From yourtable
```

This will generate unique number for each row in your table. Is this what you are looking for or am missing something here

Comment: I am not a back end guy so my knowledge is limited. But the sample i gave is just a small table. What if there are many columns and lots of repetitions? I mean if empname is repeated will that be a problem?

Comment: @antony.ouseph.k - No, number of records doesn't matter even though your data is duplicated this will generate unique number for each row. Test it with your table

Comment: I just tested. However, its showing syntactical error. Does this work in sql server 2008 R2?

Comment: @antony.ouseph.k check now.. There was a unwanted comma removed it now

Comment: Let me check. Will mark as correct answer if its works. Thanks mate

Comment: It just got tricky!! I was expecting a 1,2,3 type of row number. But apparently it is returning the rownumber of the table it was originally a part of. wont this cause an issue if joins are in action?

Comment: @antony.ouseph.k No its not clear.. It will generate numbers like 1,2,3.. and so on. Whats your problem now. Even you join some other table this will be generated on top of `Join` result

Comment: Now I understand. Its just that the serial numbers were not in any particular order. But still it works.